# How to properly install software on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, package-management

Yesterday I tried to download a program called GNU Net, but when I tried to ./configure, I recieved multiple errors indicating missing libriaries. When I tried to download the missing packages, the same thing happened. Every time I tried to download a missing package I was constantly going one step backwards trying to download the missing packages for the missing packages. It's a bureaucracy. Eventually, when I rebooted, something went wrong and I had to format my computer. My question is: Is there an easier and more convenient way to download software on Linux (Mint) if it is not listed on the Software Manager? Or maybe download a bunch of commonly used libraries?

Comment: [Installing softwares in linux -Linux Mint Community](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1525)

Comment: Have you downloaded source or `.deb` package or binary package?

Comment: `gnunet` is available on [mint repository](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gnunet) so, you can directly install it by `sudo apt-get install gnunet` (don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` first)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. First of all, the crushing majority of programs you will ever need are available in the repositories. This means they can be installed either through the software center or via the `apt-get install` command. This is the case with the very program you wanted to install which is available in the software center and can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnunet
```

If it was not there in your software center, you have misconfigured your list of software sources. Most probably, you have disabled the Ubuntu repositories which should be present for Mint installations. The `gnunet` package [is there](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnunet&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) in the Ubuntu repos so there is no reason why you couldn't install it directly.

For those programs that are not in the repositories, in most cases, you will be able to find packages for them and won't need to install from source.

Finally, for those few cases where you do need to install from source, you can get most of the needed tools on Debian-derived distributions (such as Linux Mint) by running:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

However, in many cases, when you choose to install from source you are compiling a newer version of the program which could depend on newer versions than the libraries you have installed. This can lead to what is commonly called ["dependency hell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) and is what happened to you here. When you find yourself in that situation, the `configure` script that came with the software you are attempting to install will most likely let you know what's missing. You should see messages like

```
Checking for foo: no foo found
```

`foo` can be anything at all. In most cases, this can be resolved by searching for the `foo` package and it's associated `.dev` package (the development libraries that come with whatever `foo` this happens to be). Here, I am using `libaa1` as an example

```
$ apt-cache search libaa1
libaa1 - ASCII art library
libaa1-dbg - ASCII art library, debugging symbols
libaa1-dev - ASCII art library, development kit
```

To solve the dependency, you would then run:

```
sudo apt-get install libaa1-dev
```

Luckily, you almost never need to compile from source these days so, next time, just use the software center.

Comment: On a recent Mint install my sources.list included "deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free". As Medibuntu shut down a while ago edit it out, if present, as it just adds to the confusion particularly if you are in "dependency hell"!

Comment: @MichaelJohn thanks, that's a good point. However, note that if your sources contained "precise" _anything_ you shouldn't be using it. While, strictly speaking, Mint 13 is still supported (as an LTS release, it [is supported](http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php) until 2017), the current version (Mint 17.1) is also an LTS release and is considerably more up to date. You probably have an ISO from Mint 13 which came out back when medibuntu was still functioning. Mint 13 was released in 2012, after all.

Answer (score 0):

can also install aptitude if you want easy package searching at command line

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then can do

```
sudo aptitude search gnunet
```

If you do want to build from source you will need to install the developer tools which include gcc compiler , make and libraries. And probably a good few more depending on the dependencies of what you are going to install.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```